# Mongrel plugin for Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

I am trying to install this plugin for my rails app:
https://github.com/remvee/unobtrusive_upload_progress

In the instructions, it says:

```
After installing the plugin, you’ll need to setup a Mongrel configuration script to add the following uri mappings:
```

But I checked my rails folder in config folder and there's no mongrel configuration file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install Mongrel? In the documentation of the upload gem is this remark:

> This plugin depends on Prototype.js 1.6 and Mongrel

**Update:**
It seams that you have to make a symlink from your cluster configuration file inside your rails application. See the last three steps in chapter 4 in this [tutorial](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=16).

Comment: I have mongrel server running, just can't find the configuration file.